# oracle apex not showing in windows start menu

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I am new to this forum. I am trying to get Oracle Apex along with Oracle 12c database software which I just installed. I dont see it inwindows start menu under oracle home. please help me.

Comment: This isn't the right forum for this...programmers only answer basic windows questions on holidays

Comment: when you get it up and going, don't use the start menu to access APEX, instead, bookmark the URL in your favorite browser

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 2):

If it is Oracle 12.2, well, Apex is **NOT** installed by default (as it was in previous versions).

On the other hand, Oracle suggests that you should download & install the latest Apex version, so that's not such a big drawback; why would you use 4.2 if you can have 5.1? Go to OTN downloads section, get it [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/apex/downloads/download-085147.html), follow the instructions, install it.

Some more info [here](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/multitenant-uninstall-apex-from-the-cdb-12cr1).

Comment: Thank you. I am able to install using the instructions at this link http://joelkallman.blogspot.com/2017/05/apex-and-ords-up-and-running-in2-steps.html